# Char array in struct cuts out first letter

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm just starting to learn c++ and in this whole pointer / arrays chapter I'm trying to code something to get a grip on those concepts. What I want my code to do is: 1) ask for a number of students, 2) ask for a name for each student, 3) assign an ID and name to this student in a struct, 4) print the student ID and names for verification.

The problem is the following.
Let's say for example I choose to type 3 students and type the following names:

```
JOHN
GEORGE
NICK
```

What the program prints back as student ID/Names will be:

```
0 JOHN
1 EORGE
2 ICK
```

It seems to cut the first letter of all names but the first one.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct STUDENT
{
char chName[256];
int nID;
};

int main(){

//array tests

int i=0;
int nLoops=0;                   //number entered by user
STUDENT *pnStudents;            //pointer to our student array

cout << "Enter number of students: ";
cin >> nLoops;

pnStudents = new STUDENT[nLoops];

for (i=0 ; i < nLoops ; i++)
{
    cout << endl << "Full Name of Student " << i <<": ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(pnStudents[i].chName,255);

    pnStudents[i].nID=i;
}

for (i=0 ; i < nLoops ; i++)
{
    cout << pnStudents[i].nID << " " << *pnStudents[i].chName << endl;
}

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use a debugger sooner than later.

Answer (score 0):

**[`cin.ignore();`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/)** without an argument discards from `cin`, a stream of size 1.

> **istream&  ignore ( streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF );**
>
> Extract and
>   discard characters Extracts characters from the input sequence and
>   discards them.

**Remove that.** That seems to be the only thing in your code, which could eat one character away. Also, if you need to use ignore, use something like:

```
cin.ignore(256,' ');
            ^   ^   (number of char, delim)
```

If you are trying to ignore the character you took as input for `nLoops`, you need not do it in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0 ; i < nLoops ; i++)
{
    cout << endl << "Full Name of Student " << i <<": ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(pnStudents[i].chName,255);

    pnStudents[i].nID=i;
}
```

In the first iteration of the loop, `ignore()` extracts a new line character that has been left in the stream by `cin >> nLoops;` call. `istream::getline()`, on the other hand, discards the trailing `'\n'` and so each subsequent iteration waits for and discards the first character of your input.

Move `cin.ignore()` just before the loop.